# Make readonly using getElementByName?

Tags: javascript

I need to make "readonly" a text field by place javascript code inside external JS file. I can't modify html directly because the page is located on remote server..but I can interact by adding code in external JS who is located on my own host.

The html is this:

```
<form id="newunitform" class="left" action="page.php" style="width:600px" method="post">
<fieldset>
<ul>
<li>
<label for="add">
<input type="text" value="" name="add">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="remove">
<input type="hidden" value="105" name="resource_id">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="editid">
</li>
</ul>
<label for="submit"> </label>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Add name" name="submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I tried several combination such this:

```
document.getElementByName('add').readOnly=true;
```

or this:

```
var add = document.getElementByName('add');
add.readOnly = true;
```

or this:

```
document.getElementById('newunitform');
document.getElementByName('add').readOnly=true;
```

but none work.

Comment: It's actually `getElementsByName`.  Notice the **`s`**.  It returns multiple elements.  You need to loop through and set the `readOnly` property.

Comment: Damn you right, I did not noticed the "s"...however I tested all solution proposed but none work.

Answer (score 0):

As Rocket Hazmat suggests in the comment to your question, you should use

```
document.getElementsByName('add')[0].readOnly=true;
```

Comment: tested but don't work..

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName('name')
```

returns an array. You need to use brackets or .item() to point to your element.
I suggest you using this one, in my opinion it is a better solution:

```
var newUnitForm = document.getElementById('newunitform');
newUnitForm.add.readOnly = true; //or newUnitForm['add'], it's the same
```

Comment: I tested also this but don't work..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cm5yk/
Just look at this, as you can see it works. Please explain better your problem so that we can help you.

Comment: I tested your code but don't work too..even if I seen this work well on Jsfiddle... This is strange because I use without problem some other code for apply "readonly" other" field" (but those fields have an ID so I always used document.getElementById). Maybe I'm restricted in how to use JS in for specific case... I presume I must see with the provider of remote software...

Comment: Maybe is necessary to include "input" or "text" somewhere in the code?

Comment: That's strange, in my opinion you should have some syntax errors in your code, otherwise it's fault of your browser. Which is yours?

Comment: FF20... Mmmm I don't know..Maybe the problem is the method allowed to me for interact using this external JS file. In fact all others fields where I can make modification without problem are not located on the same page of the field I try to modify.

Comment: Does firebug log something about this? You should try to use breakpoints(idk if they are also in firebug, but I think so) to understand your code

Comment: The form code I published in my question was extracted with Firebug. Normally at least one solution provided should work..so I suppose is really something about the remote software who impeach me to interact. I will ask their developers. In any case many thank for your help. cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you know there is only one element named "add", you can try something like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByName("add")[0];
elem.setAttribute("readonly", "true");   // or elem.readOnly = true;
```

If you know there is only one element named "add" inside the "newunitform" form, use LightStyle's suggestion:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("newunitform").add;
elem.setAttribute("readonly", "true");   // or elem.readOnly = true;
```

In any case, make sure the snippet is executed **after** the element in question has been rendered (e.g. you could place it in body's `onload` method.

Comment: I'm not sure this element is the only one who is named "add" however I tried and this don't work...

Comment: Have you checked that the element is already rendered ? Add `alert(elem);` at the end and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

That's true -- it's either getElementById (single element) or getElementsByName which access all the elements in the DOM that have the name you're looking for.

Once you change Element to Elements you should be able to set the readOnly attribute.

You could also try, document.getElementByNames('someElement').disabled = true; but be careful if there are multiple elements with the same name.

Also -- because syntax like this has tripped me up any number of times, if a function doesn't work as expected, I'll make sure I'm getting the object I think I'm getting by alerting some aspect of the element.

e.g. alert(document.getElementsByName('someElement').length) or alert(document.getElementsByName('someElement').name)

Good luck